# Understanding ViewState and FormData

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, viewstate

I just got started with ASP.NET MVC, and I suddenly asked myself: why does ASP.NET need `ViewState` in the first place? `FormData` is actually holding the state across postbacks. `ViewState` is only needed if the state of the control is changed, and that **change is NOT included in FormData**. For example, what if the event handler changed the control's font color?

Two questions:

- For WebForms, is that the reason for the need of `ViewState`?
- If yes, how can MVC "maintain a control's property which is NOT in `FormData`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC and WebForms are very different in this regard. The point of WebForms was to help ease WinFroms developers in to web development. For that reason the infrastructure of WebForms simulates statefullness whenever it can. `ViewState` is one of the ways this is implemented. Since the browser only posts back form fields, in WebForms the entire page is one big form and the entire page is posted to the server. The `ViewState` is a hidden field, which holds everything BUT the data in the inputs, selects, etc. which the browser posts by default.

On the other hand MVC does not try to simulate statefullness. It works more directly with `HTTP` and the basic rules of a stateless system. So when you post a form ONLY the data in the inputs, selects, etc. gets posted. Nothing else makes it back to the server.

This is why, if you want to return the same view after a post with the updated data, you have to refill the `ViewModel` with data like you did in the original get method. MVC does not take care of this for you like WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why View State in first place, your explanation is related. View State is used  to persist state across Post Backs and mainly to handle properties updated programmatic for example page with label and button and you have event handler for the button that change the label front color to red , in the page load the controls initiate the label with default color however when the button click it change the label color to red and keep that change in the view state so if anything triggered post back then after loading the controls in the page load it sets the front color to the value already saved inside the viewstate

For more details please check the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic3

MVC doesn't have viewstate, MVC is based on model binding so when a form is posted MVC framework read the httprequest parameters and try to create strongly typed object from that request and you can create your own model binder that tell the MVC how to read the http request